# How to do multiple joins correctly ? mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I want to run this query :

```
SELECT * FROM business
INNER JOIN permissions
       AS status1 ON (business.status1 = permission.permission AND permissionType ="status1")
INNER JOIN permissions
       AS status2 ON (business.status2 = permission.permission AND permissionType= "status2")
```

notice : that i do multiple join between the same tables !

this query run without errors, but it's very slow ? How to improve it ?

Comment: By adding proper indexes to your tables.

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` in front of the SQL query and run it again, put the output in your post so we can see it and help optimise your tables.

Comment: What is the db structure ?

Comment: ... normalization anybody?

Answer (score 1):

Juergen has the right idea.  You will want to **index** the proper columns on your table.  In your instance, I would index business.status1 and business.status2, as well as permissions.permissionType.  Note that there are more than one kind of index, so you will have to research what it is you are looking for.

Additionally, you have a `SELECT *`.  This is going to select all columns from your business table, all columns from your permissions table, and then all columns from your permissions table again.  This is probably not at all necessary, so I would recommend narrowing that down a bit.

Just as an extra thought, you could also change the structure of your query a bit:

```
SELECT * FROM business
INNER JOIN permissions
    AS status1 ON (business.status1 = permission.permission)
INNER JOIN permissions
    AS status2 ON (business.status2 = permission.permission)
WHERE  status1.permissionType = "status1"
    AND status2.permissionType = "status2"
```

I have no idea if that would help anything, but in general, I like to keep my joins limited to a single point of linkage.

As for the actual syntax of the command, you are doing your joins correctly.  At this point it's simply a matter of speed, and to fix that I would recommend a proper index.

Comment: THANK YOUR FOR YOUR ANSWER ! but I put status1.permissionType = "status1" with on statements, does that correct ?

Comment: @user3648409 Yes, that is still correct. I personally like to have only one statement in the `ON` clause, but having multiple statements there is perfectly legal.

Comment: @RussellUhl This query is exactly the same to MySQL, the only distinction between the on clause of an inner join and a where clause is where it appears. Your solution isn't going to be any faster. The correct solution is to normalise the data and create the correct indices.

Comment: @scragar Like I said in my answer, I wasn't sure if that would affect anything.  Thanks for the info.